# Android combine multiple booleans with elements from List<Integer>

Tags: java, android, game-development

Hello I am developing a game and working on collision detection. For now my method does not allow to add elements dynamically, as you can see I am adding collision nodes (`11,12,13,...`) manually. Here is my code:

```
private boolean isNotACollision(int index, int actualIndex) {
    return title.equals("shop")
            && index != 11 && index != 12 && index != 13 && index != 21 && index != 23 && index != 31 && index != 33
            && actualIndex != 11 && actualIndex != 12 && actualIndex != 13 && actualIndex != 21 && actualIndex != 23 && actualIndex != 31 && actualIndex != 33;
}
```

I want to dynamically build a `boolean isNotCollision()` depending on number of elements of collision in List. I want to rebuild it in a way that it hase `List<Integer> collisionNodes` as an argument.

```
private boolean isNotACollision(int index, int actualIndex, List<Integer> collisionNodes) {
    boolean shopMapCollision = (title.equals("shop")
            && WHAT HERE??;
    return shopMapCollision;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
private boolean isNotACollision(int index, int actualIndex, List<Integer> collisionNodes) {
    boolean shopMapCollision = (title.equals("shop")
            && !collisionNodes.contains(index) && !collisionNodes.contains(actualIndex));
    return shopMapCollision;
}
```